# How to add custom animations in ios scene kit swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, xcode6, scenekit

I am making a game with scene kit and part of it rolls some dice to generate a number, i have made the dice in 3DS max 2016. I can make the animations easily on 3DS max, but how would i load it into my scene? I have loaded in a dice with no animations, but I am not sure how I can load the dice animations so that it rolls.

What I intend to do is make xcode generate a number, and with that number is chooses a file out of different files, e.g. animation1, animation2.  Say the number generated was 2 it would run animation2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export animations from 3DS Max with [OpenCOLLADA plugin](http://vandaengine.org/exporting-from-3ds-max-opencollada-collada/).
Then you can get animations with [SCNSceneSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneSource_Class/index.html), like:

```swift
let src = SCNSceneSource(URL: yourSceneURL, options: nil)
let node = src.entryWithIdentifier("yourNodeID", withClass: SCNNode.self) as SCNNode
let animation = node.entryWithIdentifier("yourAnimationID", withClass: CAAnimation.self) as CAAnimation
```

Extract animations to array, and attach random one to your node with SCNNode's [addAnimation(forKey:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNAnimatable_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNAnimatable/addAnimation:forKey:)